# How to test directive loaded or not in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing, angular-directive

I have written directive which takes the directive name in parameter and load that directive dynamically as fallow:

```
.directive("loadDirective", function($compile, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                Dtype: '=type',
                subType: '@',
                data: "=data"
            },
            link: function(scope, element) {
                scope.$watch('Dtype', function() {
                    $timeout(function() {
                        var generatedTemplate = '<div ' + scope.Dtype + (scope.subType ? '-' + scope.subType + '-directive' : '-directive') + ' data="data" >dd</div>';
                        element.empty().append($compile(generatedTemplate)(scope));
                    })
                })
            },
        };
    })
```

here is my one of the directive which I will be loading it dynamically

```
.directive("dailyIntervalDirective", function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                data: '='
            },
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: '/flat-ui/tpls/daily-interval.html'
        };
    })
```

now I am trying to write test case for the loadDiretive to test it load the directive or not as follow:

```
describe("loadDirective directive", function() {
    var elm, scope;
    beforeEach(module('guideApp.directives'));
    beforeEach(module('/flat-ui/tpls/daily-interval.html'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        elm = angular.element('<load-directive type="directive" sub-type="interval" data="schedulerData"></load-directive>');
        compile = $compile;
        compile(elm)(scope);
        scope.schedulerData = {
            interval: 1,
        }
        scope.$digest();
    }));
    it("should be able to load daily directive", function() {
        scope.directive = "daily";
        var intervaldirective = elm.find('div[daily-interval-directive]');
        expect(intervaldirective.length).toEqual(1);
    });
   });
```

which is not working fine for me. I tried to log the elm but it not loading the dailyInterevalDirective.

Comment: Hi Rhushikesh, are the directives "loadDirective" and "dailyIntervalDirective" working as expected??

Comment: its working fine ? but when I writing test cases now able to test its loading or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to the question . The first issue is of `templateUrl` in the *directive definition object*. As answered by @r_goyal [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41158343/how-to-test-directive-loaded-or-not-in-angularjs/41158691#answer-41158691), Whenever template is loaded via a URL, its loaded via a `GET` call. Hence you would need to mock it using `httpBackend`.

The second part is the usage of `$timeout`. $timeout executes asynchronously, but the tests execute synchronously. This is the reason for your failing tests. To test code in `$timeout` we mock it using the [$timeout service found in angular.mock module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout). We would need to use `$timeout.flush` method on the mock `$timeout` service to force the code in the original `$timeout` to execute synchronously. Here is a fully corrected example :

```
describe("loadDirective directive", function() {
    var elm, scope, timeout, httpBackend;
    beforeEach(module('guideApp.directives'));
    beforeEach(module('/flat-ui/tpls/daily-interval.html'));
    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $timeout, $httpBackend) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        timeout = $timeout;
        httpBackend = $httpBackend;

        elm = angular.element('<load-directive type="directive" sub-type="interval" data="schedulerData"></load-directive>');
        compile = $compile;
        compile(elm)(scope);
        scope.schedulerData = {
            interval: 1,
        }
        scope.$digest();
    }));
    it("should be able to load daily directive", function() {
        scope.directive = "daily";
        httpBackend.when('GET','/flat-ui/tpls/daily-interval.html').respond("<div> Any mock template or the original template loaded as a fixture </div>");

        scope.$apply();
        timeout.flush();
        httpBackend.flush();
        var intervaldirective = elm.find('div[daily-interval-directive]');
        expect(intervaldirective.length).toEqual(1);
    });
   });
```

**There are a few points to be noted :**

- Here we call `scope.$apply()` as the code to load the directives
  dynamically is inside a *watch* . Even if you set the `Dtype` variable on
  the scope to a new value, the *watch function* will not execute
  untill a *digest cycle* is initiated.
- We then call `timeout.flush()` to force the code in `$timeout` to
  execute synchronously

[You can read more about testing `$timeout` here](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/11/unit-testing-code-that-uses-timeout-angularjs/)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your **`dailyIntervalDirective`** has a **`templateUrl`**.

Now if the directives are working, then in the tests you can expect for a **`GET`** call to *`"/flat-ui/tpls/daily-interval.html"`* using the **`httpBackend`** service. Because that template should be loaded as soon as **`dailyIntervalDirective`** directive is compiled. Hope it helps. :)

[EDIT]
Also i have a doubt whether `elm.find('div[daily-interval-directive]');` will work, as it is mentioned in [angular docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) that **`find() - Limited to lookups by tag name`**

As requested, please find sample code snippet below:

```
// -----in your spec file----  
describe("loadDirective directive", function() {
var elm, scope,$httpBackend;
beforeEach(module('guideApp.directives'));
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $compile,$httpBackend) {
    scope = $rootScope;
    $httpBackend= $httpBackend;
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/flat-ui/tpls/daily-interval.html').respond(200, 'any response you can send here, even a blank string, as it is just to test ');
    elm = angular.element('<load-directive type="directive" sub-type="interval" data="schedulerData"></load-directive>');
    compile = $compile;
    compile(elm)(scope);
    scope.schedulerData = {
        interval: 1,
    }
    scope.$digest();
}));
it("should try to load daily directive's template", function() {
    scope.directive = "daily";
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/flat-ui/tpls/daily-interval.html');
    $httpBackend.flush();
});
});
```

If this test case should pass, it means that the directive is loaded.

Comment: there are other ways as well, like instead of using an anonymous function to create "dailyIntervalDirective" you can create a named function, then spy on the function in test cases to check if it was called. ;)

Comment: I have did  beforeEach(module('/flat-ui/tpls/daily-interval.html')); to get templates

Comment: Nope... sorry that's not the way to get templates... also you don't need to get the template.. you just can check whether there is a http call to get the required template, if there is a call to the template, it confirms that the directive is loaded